# Conversion failed error in SQL for this query

Tags: sql-server

I checked this error in stackoverflow but my case and error is different. Please don't make it as duplicate.

I am getting the following error

> When converting date and/or time from character string in SQL

I have following query in my stored procedure. `work_completion_date_inst` column type is `date` and it stores date as following format. I'm using SQL Server 2008.

```
yyyy-mm-dd 
2018-04-03
2018-04-03
2018-04-14
2018-04-13

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[test]
    (@P_USER_ID INT,
     @P_START_DATE DATETIME,
     @P_END_DATE DATETIME)
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT name 
    FROM table1 
    WHERE work_completion_date_inst BETWEEN @P_START_DATE AND @P_END_DATE 
      AND user = @P_USER_ID;
END;
```

I pass following date to the stored procedure:

```
P_START_DATE = 01/04/2018
P_END_DATE =  16/04/2018
```

As it is passing from server, in the stored procedure, it arrives as `'01/04/2018 00:00:00' and '16/04/2018 00:00:00'`

So I am getting that "conversion failed error".

If I pass date less than or equal to 12, the query works. Whenever it is above 12, this error popup.

For example:

```
select name 
from table1 
where work_completion_date_inst BETWEEN '01/04/2018 00:00:00' and '12/04/2018 00:00:00';
```

Can you please help me solve this ?

Comment: There isn't anything about the number 12 that gives you a clue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SQL Server is parsing the day as month, and thus a conversion error. i.e. it see it as MM/DD/YYY. Pass it in as ANSI standard, YYYYMMDD and prevent this from happening, or do something else like use [`CONVERT()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) with the proper style, adjust the [`LANGUAGE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-language-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) setting, or set the [`DATEFORMAT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-dateformat-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) for the transaction. This has to do with the language settings. [Read more here](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/16/bad-habits-to-kick-mis-handling-date-range-queries) from Aaron Bertrand on this issue.

```
select name 
from table1 
WHERE work_completion_date_inst BETWEEN '20180401' and '20180404';
```

To convert it as you request in the comments, you can use one of two methods:

```
declare @date date = '20180416'

--SQL Server 2012 onward...
select format(@date,'yyyy-dd-MM')

--Previous versions
select stuff(stuff(@date,5,3,right(@date,3)),9,2,left(right(@date,5),2))
```

Comment: I tried following but not working "select convert(datetime,'16/04/2018 00:00:00',21)"

Comment: That's not the way you are passing it in. You need to use 103 as the style for that form. Also, you don't need to convert it to a `DATETIME` since your columns are of type `DATE`. `select convert(date,'16/04/2018 00:00:00',103)`

Comment: If I want the output as "2018-16-04" what should I do, I changed to 106 from 103 but shows "2018-04-16"

Comment: Use the exact same code in the select statment`select name, work_completition_date =  convert(varchar,work_completition_date,103)`. Why would you use 106? This doesn't have any slashes...

Comment: My bad, I see what you mean. See the edit in my answer.